# How store data from Firebase to native GearVR Framework?

Tags: android, firebase-storage, gear-vr

I want to load different cubemaps from database. Following code I used, but it is not working. It crashes every time. 
I can t get the path to the primary external storage in Android. Does anyone know how I can store Data from Database to the native GearVR Framework?

```
public class SampleActivity extends GVRActivity {

    final File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    private SampleMain main;
    private long lastDownTime = 0;

    //ref to storage firebase
    private StorageReference cubemap_ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        cubemap_ref = storageRef.child("cubemaps/cubemap_example.zip");


        final long TEN_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
        cubemap_ref.getBytes(TEN_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                File file = new File(externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath(), "cubemap.zip");
                try {
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    os.write(bytes);
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    android.util.Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        main = new SampleMain(this);
        setMain(main, "gvr.xml");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don t know why, but this code works now.